# join two lists with columns showing values from each table without duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have two tables. Each table has two columns. The first column of each table is the matching/mapping column. I have no idea how to explain what I am trying to do so I'll use an example.

## table 1

```
| col1 | col2  |
|------|-------|
| a    | one   |
| a    | two   |
| b    | three |
| c    | four  |
```

## table 2

```
| col1 | col2  |
|------|-------|
| a    | five  |
| b    | six   |
| b    | seven |
| d    | eight |
```

## desired output

```
| col1 | table1 | table2 |
|------|--------|--------|
| a    | one    | five   |
| a    | two    |        |
| b    | three  | six    |
| b    |        | seven  |
| c    | four   |        |
| d    |        | eight  |
```

(the empty cells are null)

Basically I am looking for a summary table that shows all the `col2` options for that `col1` from each table. I hope this makes sense...

Comment: Why is five only matched to one (and not two)? Similarly, why is three matched to six (and not seven)?

Comment: Cause I'm not really trying to do a join. I am joining on `col1` but I'm just trying to get a summary of each table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `FULL OUTER JOIN` and `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.col1, b.col2),
       COALESCE(a.col2, ''),
       COALESCE(b.col, '')
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Rn = Row_number()OVER(partition BY col1 ORDER BY @@SPID)
        FROM   table1) a
       FULL JOIN (SELECT *,
                         Rn = Row_number()OVER(partition BY col1 ORDER BY @@SPID)
                  FROM   table2) b
              ON a.col1 = b.col1
                 AND a.Rn = b.Rn
```

Comment: Waiting for my computer to reboot so I can test this but why use `@@SPID`?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan you can also order by `col2`

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan since there is no proper ordering required in your case I just want a constant value to use it in order by. It can be anything I just used `@@SPID`. You can use this as well `(select NULL)`

Comment: @Pரதீப் Ah. Your solution is brilliant. Thank you so very much!

Comment: Well done!  Far more elegant than my initial thought.  Also digging the @@SPID  worthy of +2

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - Thanks.. I wouldn't be surprised if would have came up with a xml solution ;)

Comment: I stared at this problem for a good 2 hours and tried everything I could think of. In the end such a simple and elegant solution does the trick. I need a vacation.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Stackoverflow exists for a reason ;)